# Type deduction of parameter and parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-deduction

I have the following code for generically wrapping Petsc objects in a `unique_ptr`, but it doesn't quite work the way I'd expect from cppreference's documentation on template type deduction: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction.

```
template <typename obj_type, typename... constructor_args>
using petsc_cons = PetscErrorCode (*)(constructor_args..., obj_type *);

template <typename obj_type> using petsc_destr = PetscErrorCode (*)(obj_type *);

template <typename obj_type, typename... constructor_args>
auto petsc_make_unique(petsc_cons<obj_type, constructor_args...> construct,
                       petsc_destr<obj_type> destroy, constructor_args... args) {
  // allocation code...
}

class NLOptimizer {
public:
  NLOptimizer(const size_t num_vars)
      : tao_ctx(petsc_make_unique<Tao>(TaoCreate, TaoDestroy,
                                       PETSC_COMM_SELF)) {}
```

This fails on g++:

```
autodiff_tao.hpp: In constructor ‘auto_diff::optimize_tao::NLOptimizer<expr_t>::NLOptimizer(expr_t, size_t)’:
autodiff_tao.hpp:45:62: error: no matching function for call to ‘petsc_make_unique<Tao>(PetscErrorCode (&)(MPI_Comm, _p_Tao**), PetscErrorCode (&)(_p_Tao**), MPI_Comm)’
   45 |                                               PETSC_COMM_SELF)) // ,
      |                                                              ^
autodiff_tao.hpp:24:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class obj_type, class ... constructor_args> auto auto_diff::optimize_tao::petsc_make_unique(auto_diff::optimize_tao::petsc_cons<obj_type, constructor_args ...>, auto_diff::optimize_tao::petsc_destr<obj_type>, constructor_args ...)’
   24 | auto petsc_make_unique(petsc_cons<obj_type, constructor_args...> construct,
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
autodiff_tao.hpp:24:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
autodiff_tao.hpp:45:62: note:   mismatched types ‘_p_Tao*’ and ‘ompi_communicator_t’
   45 |                                               PETSC_COMM_SELF)) // ,
```

Clang is able to deduce the parameter pack types and compiles the code above. Is this a bug in g++, clang, or am I relying on undefined behaviour here?

I've attempted this compilation on multiple minor versions of clang 9 and g++ 9, and several less successful variations of the code above.

Comment: `petsc_cons` relies on undefined behavior. Parameter packs can be deduced only if they are the ***last*** parameter.

Comment: I'm not trying to deduce the types for petsc_cons; those are specified explicitly. Is this an issue here? If it is, then I likely can't generically wrap petsc functions,  since they all follow this pattern.

Comment: I think I understand now; putting petsc_cons in the non-deducable context fixed this issue because it prevented the compiler from trying to deduce the type from petsc_cons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like gcc is trying to deduce `constructor_args` from `construct`, and deducing them as an empty parameter pack.

To just get it to deduce from `constructor_args... args`, just put it in a non_deducible context (Like `std::type_identity_t<petsc_cons<obj_type, constructor_args...>> construct`). You have to make sure that `constructor_args... args` matches exactly though.